# Mocking property file in spring mvc for Junit testing

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to write a Junit test case for my repository class which is uses a property file. I am using spring 3.2.4. problem is i am not able to. Below is my code snippet :

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:properties/filterTemplate.properties")
public class FilterTemplateRepository  {

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public Map<String,List<FilterTemplate>> getBean()
    {
        Map<String,List<FilterTemplate>> filterTemplateMap=new HashMap<String,List<FilterTemplate>>();
        // basic code

        return filterTemplateMap;

    }

    public List<FilterTemplate> getModuleData(String moduleName)
    {

        return getBean().get(moduleName);
    }
}
```

and below is my Test file :

```
public class FilterTemplateRepositoryTest{

    private FilterTemplateRepository filterTemplateRepository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        filterTemplateRepository= Mockito.mock(FilterTemplateRepository.class);;
    }

    @Test
    public void testgetModuleData() {
        String moduleName="dashboard";
        List<FilterTemplate> filterTemplatelist=new ArrayList<FilterTemplate>();;
        filterTemplatelist=filterTemplateRepository.getModuleData(moduleName);
        assertEquals(4,filterTemplatelist.size());
    }

}
```

But this is failing saying expected was zero but it should be 4. Am i missing something. any good explains on mocking property file in Junit testing is most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The annotation will need mocking

there appears to be a good explaination here http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/UsingPropertySourceAndEnvironment.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use a standard build tool like maven, you have different classpaths for testing and production. Just place a test-specific properties file in src/test/resources, it will take precedence over the one in src/main/resources